# Map a string (usernames) to UUID's in perl

Tags: perl

How would you do a one may mapping between a string and a UUID in perl.

I need integrate a legacy perl system that assigns users usernames, with a java system that assigns users a UUID.

(Only needs to be one way, that is, username to UUID, I don't need to go back the other way)

I was thinking something like this, although I bet theres a much simpler way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my $username = "bob";
my $hash = md5_hex($username);
my $uuid = substr($hash, 0, 8)."-".substr($hash,8,4)."-".substr($hash,12,4)."-".substr($hash,16,4)."-".substr($hash,20,32);
print "$uuid\n";
```

Comment: Perhaps some other digesting method, ie. `sha`?

Comment: @mpapec MD5 and UUID are both 128 bits wide, so it seems like an obvious choice — until you realize that there's a format to UUIDs, and not every 128-bit combination is valid.

Comment: @hobbs tnx for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest following [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html#section-4.3)'s guidelines on generating UUIDs from names.

First, generate a random UUID and store it as part of your app / configuration.

Then:

```
use Data::UUID;
my $ug = Data::UUID->new;
my $namespace = $ug->from_string("65faad2c-7841-4b60-a7f4-560db1c5e683");
my $uuid = $ug->create_from_name_str($namespace, $username);
```

Where you replace "65faad2c-7841-4b60-a7f4-560db1c5e683" with your own randomly generated UUID.

This is guaranteed to generate valid UUIDs (your md5 method isn't), and if you ever have another legacy app that needs to be imported into the new system, conflicts will be avoided just by giving that app its own random UUID to use as a seed.